# Would it be 'meet' or 'have met' in this structure?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, syntactic-analysis, perfect-aspect

If I bumped into someone, who happened to be called John, yesterday, and I am telling someone else of the encounter, would I say:

> I happened to meet John yesterday.

or

> I happened to have met John yesterday.

?

The question, in other words, is this:

Does the sense of past lie in the act of 'happening,' or the act of 'meeting,' or in both. It confuses me because a) I already happened to meet [?] him, and b) I already 'met' him.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the choice is between *"I happened to meet John yesterday."* and *"I happen to have met John yesterday"*. So you can put the past in the *happening* or in the *meeting*, but not in both. Notice that in speech, *"happen to"* and *"happened to"* sound almost perfectly identical, even though they're different in writing. This means that even native English speakers are liable to get it wrong in writing.

Comment: To elaborate on your comment, it could make sense to use "happened to have met" if the pluperfect is intended, but it would only make sense in the context of another event. "I happened to have met John yesterday before bumping into his ex-girlfriend that afternoon."

Answer (score 2):

"to meet" refers to the bare event of "meeting", which was in the past, hence "happened to meet".

"to have met" refers to the state of "having met", which is a present state, hence "happen to have met". I don't think there is any use of "happen" where you would need to refer to a past state, and so "happened to have met" just won't be used.

The differences between "happened to meet" and "happen to have met" can be seen in the following:

> Just yesterday, I happened to meet him.
>
> *Just yesterday, I happen to have met him. (WRONG because "happen" is semantically incompatible with "just yesterday")
>
> I happen to have met him just yesterday. (correct because "just yesterday" here modifies "to have met him")